# Which certificate was used in secure connection

Tags: google-chrome

I have certificates installed in Google Chrome which is used when connecting to remote host. How to know which exactly certificate was used?

Comment: Which certificates are you referring to?  Those used to create an encryption tunnel or those used for client authentication?

Comment: I have feeling that several certificates are used while connecting to remote host. How to distinguish authentication and SSL tunnel certificates?

Comment: This tells you how to view the certificate (or chain) used for SSL https://www.howtogeek.com/292076/how-do-you-view-ssl-certificate-details-in-google-chrome/.  If you're not sure about the difference between client authentication and SSL certificates then likely that's what you're looking for.

Comment: In my case lock sign shows remote host certificate. My questions is about certificates that are installed in Google Chrome under `Manage device certificates`

Comment: Ok, got it.  Yeah, that would not be shown under the lock.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Chrome will prompt you for which client certificate to use

[image: example]

The only reason you might not see this when a client certificate is used, is if someone enables cert [auto-select](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::AutoSelectCertificateForUrls). If so, this should show up in `chrome://policy/`, or you can check the windows registry here to be sure it hasn't been enabled:

```
HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
HKCU:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
```

Comment: Strange, but I don't see `Google` section in `HKLM:\Software\Policies\` or `HKCU:\Software\Policies\`. And yes, I can see certificate selection menu, but only once when I restart Chrome. I would like to ask me each time or give this kind of info somewhere

Comment: @vico The Google reg key only shows up after policies are applied, so it's normal to be missing. If you want it to ask **every** time, use incognito/InPrivate browsing. If you find it's not prompting at all, there are some other causes listed in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014288/browser-is-not-prompting-for-a-client-certificate